# "iptables -P OUTPUT DROP" blocks DDWRT's web interface

Tags: linux, networking, router, dd-wrt, iptables

When I do `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` it blocks DDWRT's web interface.

That is I am not able to access `http://192.168.1.1` via Firefox.

I put this rules before changing the chain policy to drop:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Why is `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` blocking the management interface?

Comment: you need to accept RELATED,ESTABLISHED outbound packets.

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTPUT` chain specifically targets packets generated on the host(i.e. DD-WRT box).  This is how the web server communicates.  As mentioned by cybernard, allowing ESTABLISHED connections will allow you to initiate the connection from a browser(assuming your `INPUT` rules allow it).